# OBJKT graphql Api

Tags: node, api, nft

I am developing an API with the goal of retrieving all recent listings. I'm utilizing the OBJKT API for various functionalities within my API. However, whenever I use the 'order by' clause in the 'listing_active' endpoint (with any parameter), the OBJKT API consistently returns an error. Does anyone know why this is happening and if there's a possible solution?

The code I'm using is quite simple:

```
query MyQuery {
  listing_active(order_by: {timestamp: asc}) {
    id
  }
}
```

Strangely, if I use 'listing' (or any other) instead of 'listing_active', it works perfectly fine.

The error message I receive is as follows:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "database query error",
      "extensions": {
        "path": "$",
        "code": "unexpected"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated.

If anyone want to try:
https://public-api-v3-20221206.objkt.com/explore/